# Do item lookup /mapping in underscore template

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am trying to do an object lookup in underscore:

```
var imdbTypeMapping = {
  'movie': 'Movie',
  'short': 'Short Film',    
}

var detailsTmpl = _.template('<p<%= imdbTypeMapping[item.titleType] %></p>'
```

Though I get the following error: `imdbTypeMapping is not defined`. How would I do an item lookup in the underscore template?

Comment: can you post full code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
var imdbTypeMapping = {
    'movie': 'Movie',
    'short': 'Short Film',    
}

var detailsTmpl = _.template('<p><%= imdbTypeMapping[item.titleType] %></p>');

var text = detailsTmpl({
    item: {
       titleType: 'movie'
    }
});

console.log(text);
```

Comment: thank you, that example is very helpful, it was in calling the `detailsTmpl` that I did not define the additional mapping variable.

Answer (score 1):

Answer by @Will is also great. But alternatively, you could also do this

```
var imdbTypeMapping = {
    'movie': 'Movie',
    'short': 'Short Film',    
}

var detailsTmpl = _.template('<p><%= imdbTypeMapping[item.titleType] %></p>', {
    item: {
       titleType: 'movie'
    }
});
```